# Can't type or move my mouse when in Ubuntu login screen

Tags: gnome, login, mouse

I'v just used Ubuntu for couple of months. I installed gnome-shell and rebooted my Ubuntu. Then I stucked in a login loop, which means when I logged in correctly, a blacks creen of errors appeared and the login screen came back.

I searched the solution, I saw a lot of people solved this problem by using `sgfxi`. But when I ran the script successfully, I reboot and my login screen was completely freezed. I can't enter anything from the keyboard or move my mouse.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.